# error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '&'

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I found [this link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091203110734AAHlSdb), but it's not my issue.

I'm getting the error at the declaration.

Here is my declaration:

```
typedef struct
{
    int buffer[10];
} Special_t;

void Special_Reset(Special_t &context);
```

This is in a .c file.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to compile it for Windows.  This is part of a cross-platform project.  This exact code works fine using an embedded C compiler.

I've also tried building with the command line using this:

```
cl main.c /I. /TC
```

The /TC means "force the c-compiler" as opposed to the C++ compiler.  It didn't work either.

Comment: Well `&` in this context in C++ means a reference. C doesn't have references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `&` to pass by reference is only valid in C++.  Try passing by pointer or switching to a C++ compiler.

Comment: Ah ha. :-)  The embedded compiler has a helpful hybrid C/C++ compiler with a sort of mixed syntax. Pass by reference is allowed in it.  I forgot. Thanks!